# How to call a function inside a function from outside of it?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have a function that performs fetch and processes this data:

```
async function fetchData(){
    const res = await fetch("./data.json");
    const data = await res.json();

    // processing one-time code

    function doSome() {
    // code that looks for something in data and processes it(I'm going to call this function many times)
    }
    doSome()
}
fetchData();
```

I can call the doSome function inside fetchData, but I need to call doSome outside fetchData.

How can I not process one-time code and only run doSome?

Comment: you can pass the function to `fetchData` and then access it as a parameter which you can invoke after the await completes.

Comment: When you call it outside the function, which `data` should it use? Does it make sense to pass `data` as an argument to `doSome`? If so, you could simply turn it into a normal outer function and just call it from `fetchData` passing it `data` as an argument repeatedly...

Comment: I have the biggest problem with fetch. I either need to put a wild chain with .then or do everything in 1 function (json is processed in doSome) and I don't know how to save data from fetch so that I can reuse it later in an external function.

Comment: are you on a browser that requires a polyfill or you are using native `fetch`?

Comment: Newest FF and newest chrome using fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doSome(data) {
// code that looks for something in data and processes it(I'm going to call this function many times)
}

async function fetchData(){
    const res = await fetch("./data.json");
    const data = await res.json();

    // processing one-time code
    return data;
}

let data;

fetchData().then(fetchResult => {
    //Stuff you want to do once you have the data.
    data = fetchResult;
    doSome(data);
    // Handle any queued events.
});

// Pseudo-code event handler you can attach before data is ready 
const eventHandler = (event) => { 
    if (!data) { 
        // Pseudo-code denoting a function that queues an event to be executed later
        queueEvent(event) 
    } else { 
        doSome(data)
    }
}
```

So I removed doSome from the scope of fetchData into the module's scope. Then I changed fetchData to return the data, so we can use that result later on. Once it resolves, it sets variable `data`, and you can re-use it, and do any required actions in the `then` callback. Depending on your needs, you can either add event listeners there, or queue events and fire the handlers requiring data once it resolves. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The inner function scope is confined to the outer function. Therefore it cannot be called from outside, similarly to a variable declared from inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two independent actions where the output of one is the input of the other. So, do two separate functions and you get cleaner code.

```
async function fetchData(){
    const res = await fetch("./data.json");
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
}
const json = fetchData();


function doSome(json) {
    // code that looks for something in data and processes it(I'm going to call this 
     function many times)
}

doSome(json);
doSome(json);
doSome(json);
doSome(json);
```

You can always encapsulate them in a JSON/Object if you want to ship them around together. Play with exporting just the right methods and keep a global (to this file) variable holding the JSON.

```
    let json = {};
    async function fetchData(){
        const res = await fetch("./data.json");
        const data = await res.json();
        json = data;
    }


  function doSome() {
  console.log(json);
        // code that looks for something in data and processes it(I'm going to call this 
         function many times)
    }

   //You probably want to call this from the outside, not in this file.
   doSome();
   doSome();
   fetchData();
   doSome();
   doSome();

   //not sure what is your functionality, so not sure what you would need to export here
   export default {
       fetchData,
       doSome
   }
```

Comment: console.log your response and adjust, I do not know what ajax lib you are using and what your server returns. and notice Ichanged the code, removed the second await which is probably faulty.

Comment: Forgot to add the symbol <_<

Comment: I tried your first option, `console.log(json(or data)) ` returned the promise instead of json.

Comment: if res.json() returns a promise, either add back the await or use the .then(()=>{}) method to handle the promise.

Comment: Please tell me, how do I get json out of function in this case?

Comment: Inside the function it returns json, but again outside the function it gives promise

Comment: if you do `const data = await res.json();` what is the value of `data`?

Comment: Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Answer (score 0):

Make doSome a closure and return it from the method.

```
async function fetchData() {
  // do your fetch logic
  const doSome = () => {
    // logic
  };

  return doSome;
}

const doSome = await fetchData();
doSome();
```

The closure will make sure you retain proper context of the wrapping method it was declared in, ensuring it can access the properties declared in the fetchData method context.

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators - on line with doSome = await fetchData

Comment: You either have to have top level async methods available or you have to do a simple async function wrapper around the code you wrote.